# Google Sheets - Make sure cells have a value before executing script

Tags: google-apps-script, worksheet

I want to have a script execute only if all required cells contain information.

[image: How a row should look before being sent]

The above sheet shows how the layout is. The rows that need to be populated for the script to start are columns B to G

An extra feature that I would also like but is not required is if the user does not fill in all the cells required it will highlight them in red and delete the values in columns H & I of the active row in question.

Below is the script that executes when column H has the value "Completed"

```html
function moveComplete() {
  Utilities.sleep(200);
  
  var sheetNameToWatch = "REQUEST"; 
  var columnNumberToWatch = 9;
  var valueToWatch = "COMPLETED";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "ARCHIVE";
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setDataValidation(null).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    sheet.insertRows(lastrow, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trigger a checking (depending on what value you need) on **all** the cells that correspond as a *required value* with [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit). Afterwards, simply trigger your `moveComplete()` function to populate the rest of the other cells you need.

This [Google Docs Help Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3Iz9y9OSLMk) might give you an idea on how to do it. Just modify some of the code snippets that are already provided there. Other helpful docs:

- [Google AppScipt Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Google AppScript Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)